# assigning the value is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

The picture is rotating but the value of variable `$points` is not assigned!

What I want is when user clicks on the image it rotates and then it alerts.

Please answer, I'm stuck on it.

```js
var $toggle = 0;
var $points = 0;
    $('.one').click(function () {
        if ($toggle == 0) {
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
            $points = 100;
            $toggle = 1;
        }
        else if ($toggle == 1) {
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
            $toggle = 2;
            $points = 0;
        }
        else if ($toggle == 2) {
            $toggle = 3;
            $points = 0;
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(270deg)");
        }
        else if ($toggle == 3) {
            $toggle = 0;
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(360deg)");
            $points = 0;
        }
        else {
            
        }
    });
if ($points >= 100) {

    alert("next mission");

}
else {

    //nothing

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="Assets/pipe.png" class="c1 one">
```

Comment: Put this `if ($points >= 100) {alert("next mission");}` at the end of the `click` event

Comment: You set the value of $points to 100 the first click, but only alert if it is over 100? Plus its outside the function so the if statement will only run once before you have clicked

Comment: @DavidB Over or equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put if($points >= 100) condition code inside $(".one").click event.

```
var $toggle = 0;
var $points = 0;
    $('.one').click(function () {
        if ($toggle == 0) {
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
            $points = 100;
            $toggle = 1;
        }
        else if ($toggle == 1) {
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
            $toggle = 2;
            $points = 0;
        }
        else if ($toggle == 2) {
            $toggle = 3;
            $points = 0;
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(270deg)");
        }
        else if ($toggle == 3) {
            $toggle = 0;
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(360deg)");
            $points = 0;
        }
        else {

        }
        // put it inside this click event 
        if ($points >= 100) {
            alert("next mission");
        }
        else {
            //nothing
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put if condition inside the click event like this:

```js
var $toggle = 0;
var $points = 0;
    $('.one').click(function () {
        alert($points);
        if ($toggle == 0) {
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
            $points = 100;
            $toggle = 1;
        }
        else if ($toggle == 1) {
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
            $toggle = 2;
            $points = 0;
        }
        else if ($toggle == 2) {
            $toggle = 3;
            $points = 0;
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(270deg)");
        }
        else if ($toggle == 3) {
            $toggle = 0;
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(360deg)");
            $points = 0;
        }
        else {
            
        }
         if ($points >= 100) {

           alert("next mission");

         }
         else {

             //nothing

         }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="Assets/pipe.png" class="c1 one">
```